# How do you convert from shared_ptr<derived> to shared_ptr<base> when returning from a function?

Tags: c++

Lets say we have an abstract class called Vehicle. A bunch of classes will inherit from Vehicle such as Boat, Car, Truck, etc.

I want to create a function which returns me a pointer to a vehicle given certain parameters that I pass in. I don't need access to the underlying Vehicle. I have something like this so far:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Vehicle> create_vehicle(Environment e, Cost c) {
    if (e.is_water()) {
        boost::shared_ptr<Boat> boat(new Boat());
        boat->set_location("USA");
        boat->set_environment(e);

        ...

        return boat; // How should I return the shared pointer here?
                     // I get an error for doing this 
                     // "Vehicle is an inaccessible base of boat"

    } else if (e.is_land()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I return the shared_ptr of derived when the return value of the function is a shared_ptr? Is casting necessary or is there a way to do without casting? I guess I could also just return the derived class by value but I do not want to make another copy of the vehicle when I return it.

Comment: make `Vehicle` a `public` base of `Boat` ?

Comment: If you inheritance is protected or private, you can still use `shared_ptr`, but you'll have to cast the raw pointer manually. You can create a `shared_ptr` that shares ownership with another `shared_ptr` but points to a different (potentially unrelated) object.

Comment: As is often the case, the OP doesn't show enough code.  I suspect that @Walter has got it right, but without the definition for `Boot`, who knows.

Comment: @dyp: That's the C-style cast that has no template-style equivalent at all, right?

Comment: @BenVoigt Umm.. that's not what I meant. A `shared_ptr` object contains at least two pointers: one to the object pointed to, and one to the bookkeeping object. Those two pointers do not need to be related; hence you can manage one object and point to an unrelated object. For example, manage an object and point to a data member. This feature can be (ab)used to share ownership with a private base class, even if `shared_ptr` itself cannot convert between those two. How you convert to the private base class then is your problem (friendship / C-style cast / ..)

Comment: @dyp: I know that.  You mentioned getting the private base class pointer by "you'll have to cast the raw pointer manually".  I'm just observing that I think this cast is only supported by the C-style cast; none of the template-style cast operators can do it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I'm sorry, I realized that too late and added a short note at the end of my comment. Well, I had friendship or other "usual" accessibility features in mind for my first comment, not the C-style cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your error message it *appears* that you used private or protected inheritance between `Vehicle` and `Boat` rather than public.

Comment: Most likely, he just forgot to specify.  And for `class`, inheritance defaults to private.  As a general rule, always specify the access when inheriting.

Comment: Oops, you are exactly right. I forgot to make the inheritance public

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `static_pointer_cast`  - it is in a way equivalent to static_cast for shared_pointers. Look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#functions

Comment: Just FYI, using `std::move` is a huge optimization to convert to type `T` without needing to increment/decrement the reference count. For example: `return static_pointer_cast<T>(std::move(ptr))`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a shared_ptr to Vehicle and use it

```
boost::shared_ptr<Vehicle> create_vehicle(Environment e, Cost c) 
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Vehicle> vehicle;
    if (e.is_water()) {
        Boat *boat = new Boat();
        boat->set_location("USA");
        boat->set_environment(e);

        vehicle.reset(boat); // Assign the pointer to the result

    } else if (e.is_land()) {
        ...
    }
    return vehicle;
}
```

Comment: You haven't define `boat` anywhere.

Comment: The error indicated by the OP, "Vehicle is an inaccessible base of boat", will prevent `vehicle.reset(boat)` from working as well.  In addition, this approach gratuitously breaks exception safety.